# Are there any video codec that support a timecode embedded in them?

Tags: video, video-encoding

I was wondering if any of the video standards support embedding a timecode when capturing/recording.

I have a requirement to record and playback multiple video streams, whilst keeping them in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need an embedded timecode in the video for this, the video header has enough fields to help you figure this out.

Each frame is "timestamped" by this:

```
start time + sum of all previous frame durations
```

Given you have a relative starting point (which can be stored in the video header per track) you can keep track of when each frame should be displayed.

Durations are in the [stts atom](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=QuickTime_container#stts) and you can put the relative starting point in the [media header atom](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=QuickTime_container#mdhd) (notice the creation/modification time areas)

Answer (score 5):

Most broadcast video codecs allow tagging frames with a SMPTE timecode or a frame position.

- MPEG User Data may carry timecodes. [MPEG-2 TS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) packets have a timecode.
- DV frames are encoded with a timecode.
- H.264 is very flexible with regards to timing information. Frames are encoded with a frame position. There may be additional timing data in the SPS NAL Unit if timing_info_present_flag is set.

There are notable exceptions. Some intra-frame video formats such as JPEG-2000 or DNxHD do not carry timecode information.

Extra timecode information is usually carried by the container format (QuickTime, MPEG TS, MXF, etc..).

Answer (score 1):

If video size doesn't matter: DV has the timecode in every frame.
I think MPEG 1/2 can also have a timecode (SMPTE timecode) in it's data stream.
h264 can embed variable data in it's datastream as NAL-SEI-UserData-Block. IPCam's like Axis and Basler embed the cameratime and triggerdata in such DataBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Timecode is not related to exactly codec itself. "Codec" is a method of encoding, of video in this case, and timecode is attached on top of it and is typically written along with encoded video frames into file. Almost all formats keep frame time, some formats have fixed frame rate, some allow more flexibility.

On the playback it is the matter of framework to enforce timestamps, and present frames on time, multiple stream in sync in particular.